Angular Logs to Elastic and Kibana
Im using Angular 16, and already have the backend logs being sent to Elastic with the help of Serilog. Im able to see them in the log stream of Kibana, however I also wanted to send longs from the Angular application (user interactions, payloads, errors, and other custom logs). Besides this, I would also want to add labels to each log.
I've tried with APM with Angular Integration but I believe that's more for monitoring and not for logging, also thought of ngx-logger and Logstash, but can't seem to send anything from ngx-logger to Elastic, and Logstash didn't really understand how can I send something to it.
Can someone help me on this?
Thanks for the help!
